# Building projects with emscripten - stuck on acorn-optimizer

Tags: c++, emscripten, asm.js

I'm writing a medium-sized C++ program (around 900 lines; quite a few templates, idiomatic C++, only RAII and collections, no raw arrays, no pointers, no manual memory allocation). Native build for my application takes around 5 minutes, but problems start with emscripten build.

Webassembly is emitted relatively quickly, in a few seconds. The build stalls on acorn-optimizer trying to optimize the libstdc++ runtime (?). It's been running for 20 minutes, and i tried to re-run and kill it multiple times to get it to build my application.

I use the following commandline:

```
em++ -std=c++20 -o tau.html lexer.cpp symtab.cpp parser.cpp decl.cpp tau.cpp -O3 -s WASM=1
```

`em++` launches a process with the following commandline:

```
/usr/bin/node /usr/share/emscripten/tools/acorn-optimizer.js /tmp/emscripten_temp_gwg74gkp/tau.js AJSDCE minifyWhitespace
```

which is constantly using a single core of my processor and ~50MB (fluctuating) of RAM, and due to it, the compilation doesn't finish.

[image]

`tau.js` contents follow: [link](https://b.catgirlsare.sexy/RZRADQm6.js). I managed to (somewhat) track down the issue - a 800-line C++ project seems to be too big for Emscripten to handle. asm.js output is well over 6 megabytes on `-g3 -O0` build (the one which doesn't run the minifier)

[image]

I was surprised at the inefficiency and horribleness of the Emscripten ABI.

My question follows - how do I get this project to build and optimize? Do i have to leave the build overnight every time I want to compile something? Is there a better tool for compiling C++ and targetting webasm or asm.js?

I gave up on `-O3` and decided that I'll try `-O1`, without success - compiler crashes:

```
em++ -std=c++20 -o tau.html lexer.cpp symtab.cpp parser.cpp decl.cpp tau.cpp -O1 -s WASM=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/em++.py", line 14, in <module>
    sys.exit(emcc.run(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/emcc.py", line 2156, in run
    post_link(options, wasm_target, wasm_target, target)
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/emcc.py", line 2320, in post_link
    generate_html(target, options, js_target, target_basename,
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/emcc.py", line 3075, in generate_html
    minify_html(target)
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/emcc.py", line 3049, in minify_html
    shared.check_call(['htmlmin', opts, '--', filename, filename])
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 104, in check_call
    return run_process(cmd, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 94, in run_process
    ret = subprocess.run(cmd, check=check, input=input, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1756, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
make: *** [Makefile:44: webasm] Error 1
```

I also tried `-g3 -O0`, but the output code doesn't work:

[image]

7zipped output of emscripten for -g3 -O0 follows: [link](https://b.catgirlsare.sexy/gki_14xl.7z). I don't think my source code is significant here - the issue clearly happens within emscripten runtime.

For the record, I'm using emscripten built using emsdk on 24 January this year, that is, 2021.

It doesn't matter if i pick asm.js or webasm target, because the bottleneck which is stalling the compilation is modifying the emscripten-generated boilerplate JS (which is enough to stall the compiler, if the C++ code wasn't enough).

Comment: Hi, I am regularly building a ~35K line c++ project with emscripten and haven't experienced anything like this. For the size of executables, one has to take into account the fact that all libraries that would be linked dynamically in native code get merged into one binary with emscripten. 
Have you tried to compile any sample c++ code to check that your build environment is working? If you can provide an example project that reproduces this issue I am happy to try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an entire 3D engine compiled to 1.2mb in `.wasm` file. Few things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure the build is for release instead of debug.
2. Ensure `NO_DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING` is set to 1. [Documentation](https://emscripten.ru/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-Code.html#optimizing-code-exception-catching)
3. Set emcc flag `-s O3`. [Documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-o3)

I think the main issue is the debug build. I remember my 1.2mb WASM module became 100+ mb in size when built in debug. I just left it in release configuration by default because of it.